# Applying styles to html page using stylesheets included in xml

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml

I'm trying to create a theme switcher using which user can change website themes by clicking buttons. i don't want to use either local storage or cookies. I'm trying to do it using xml. I can attach stylesheet to a xml file and run the html. but this forces style changes in xml file. html page doesn't change. how do i go about it. Please help.

```
    <html>
<body>
    <h3>Populate Data from XML file using Jquery</h3>
    <input id="btnGetData" type="button" value="Populate Data from XML File" />
    <div id="UpdatePanel" style="padding:20px 10px">
        <form action="datacheck.xml">
            <input type="submit" value="blue">
        </form>
        <form action="datacheck1.xml">
            <input type="submit" value="red">
        </form>
        <form action="datacheck2.xml">
            <input type="submit" value="green">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnGetData").click(function () {
            $("#UpdatePanel").html("Please wait...");
            $.ajax({
                url: "datacheck.xml",
    url:"datacheck1.xml",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnError
            });
        });
    });

    function OnSuccess(xml) {
        var tableContent = "
                <table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>" +
                            "
                    <tr>" +
                                "
                        <th>TITLE</th>" +
                                "
                        <th>ARTIST</th>" +
                                "
                        <th>COUNTRY</th>" +
                                "
                        <th>COMPANY</th>" +
                                "
                        <th>PRICE</th>" +
                                "
                        <th>YEAR</th>" +
                            "
                    </tr>";
        $(xml).find('CD').each(function () {
            tableContent += "
                    <tr>" +
                                "
                        <td>" + $(this).find('TITLE').text() + "</td>" +
                                "
                        <td>" + $(this).find('ARTIST').text() + "</td>" +
                                "
                        <td>" + $(this).find('COUNTRY').text() + "</td>" +
                                "
                        <td>" + $(this).find('COMPANY').text() + "</td>" +
                                "
                        <td>" + $(this).find('PRICE').text() + "</td>" +
                                "
                        <td>" + $(this).find('YEAR').text() + "</td>" +
                            "
                    </tr>";
        });
        tableContent += "
                </table>";
        $("#UpdatePanel").html(tableContent);
    }

    function OnError(data) {
        $("#UpdatePanel").html("Error! Please try again.");
    }



</script>
```

Comment: Use jQuery and change CSS link to other theme file. Or better, show what you have done so far with your code.

Comment: this is what i have done.  i have attached 3 css files to 3 different xml files.(<?xml-stylesheet href="style2.css"  type="text/css"?>)  and created 3 buttons. therefore if i run the html page and click any button, css in xml are forced to change. there is no change of styles in html

Comment: You are loading XML, getting it's content, but not styles. You have to change current page CSS links instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading XML content, but not it's CSS. To change HTML css, you have to change source of file dynamically:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#style').attr('href', $(this).data('url'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" id="style">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="btn btn-success" data-url="https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">style 1</div>
  <div class="btn btn-primary" data-url="https://bootswatch.com/slate/bootstrap.min.css">style 2</div>
</div>
```